# prove that the language LRE is decidable

Tags: turing-machines, computability, reductions

given the language LRE= { 〈M〉 | L(M) ∈ RE }
prove that the language can be found in R( which means it's decidable).
if i use reduction, how can i use for example ADFA language to solve it?
and is there any other way to prove it except for reduction?
i'm studying to an exam so it would help me a lot.

Comment: Hint: Take a look at the definition of RE.

Comment: As Yuval suggested, what's another description of LRE?

Comment: well the language LRE receives a machine(M) that belongs to RE, so the output of the machine would be: accept, reject or loop. so if i want to prove that this language is decidable, should i build an alternative machine that receives M and has 2 outputs? accept if M accepts, and reject if M rejects or goes on loop?

Comment: Hint: that language is much easier than it may look. Find a simpler equivalent definition (using Yuval's suggestion).